# Magento 2.4.3 Page Builder Addons

Tags: magento, e-commerce, magento2

Does anyone know of any extensions/add-ons that already exists that provides additional components to the core Magento page builder, such as an image gallery, form builder, accordions, etc. I understand that these can be custom built following https://devdocs.magento.com/page-builder/docs/content-types/create/introduction.html

Answer (score 1):

Since 2.3.4 Magento Page Builder was released to Community version, but quite complex and buggies (personal opinion), the UI/UX is hard to use and low side response, I changed to this module https://github.com/Goomento/PageBuilder since then.
Hope this can help

Answer (score -2):

Create custom pages and content blocks without writing a line of code with the Magento CMS Page Builder extension.

- Create and edit CMS, category, and product pages
- Use 30+ building elements to create unique page designs
- Import/export, delete or restore any page version
- Provide mobile-responsive design
- Compatible with Magento 2 themes

You can refer to [this module](https://amasty.com/page-builder-for-magento-2.html?gclid=Cj0KCQiA_8OPBhDtARIsAKQu0gZYy7apAF5IZemYmsoxBnNtBIFhDRmZxuRdhvlj_fhjsT3w_tYI6_8aAjguEALw_wcB).